# EF Core LINQ groups results of the query incorrectly

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a entity like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    //other properties

}
```

Which has a unique constraint on `{ RegistrationNumber, Model, Code, /*two other properties*/ }`

I'm trying to query the database to get an object that's structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Model1",
    "codes": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "registrationNumbers": ["2", "3"]
      },
      {
        "name":"BBB",
        "registrationNumbers": ["3", "4"]
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "name": "Model2",
    "codes": [
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "registrationNumbers": ["4", "5"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I.e. the list of Models, each models has a list of Codes that can co-appear with it, each code has a list of Registration Numbers that can appear with that Model and that Code.

I'm doing a LINQ like this:

```
var vehicles = _context.Vehicles.Where(/*some additional filters*/)
return await vehicles.Select(v => v.Model).Distinct().Select(m => new ModelFilterDTO()
      {
          Name = m,
          Codes = vehicles.Where(v => v.Model== m).Select(v => v.Code).Distinct().Select(c => new CodeFilterDTO()
          {
              Name = c,
              RegistrationNumbers = vehicles.Where(v => v.Model == m && v.Code == c).Select(v => v.RegistrationNumber).Distinct()
          })
      }).ToListAsync();
```

Which gets translated into this SQL query:

```
SELECT [t].[Model], [t2].[Code], [t2].[RegistrationNumber], [t2].[Id]
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT [v].[Model]
      FROM [Vehicles] AS [v]
      WHERE --additional filtering
  ) AS [t]
  OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT [t0].[Code], [t1].[RegistrationNumber], [t1].[Id]
      FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT [v0].[Code]
          FROM [Vehicles] AS [v0]
          WHERE /* additional filtering */ AND ([v0].[Model] = [t].[Model])
      ) AS [t0]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT [v1].[RegistrationNumber], [v1].[Id], [v1].[Code]
          FROM [Vehicles] AS [v1]
          WHERE /* additional filtering */ AND ([v1].[Model] = [t].[Model])
      ) AS [t1] ON [t0].[Code] = [t1].[Code]
  ) AS [t2]
  ORDER BY [t2].[Id]
```

Running this query in the SQL Server gets me correct sets of values. But when I perform the LINQ, I get an object like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Model1",
    "codes": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "registrationNumbers": [/* every single registration number that is present among the records that passed the filters*/]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the problem may be, and how to fix it?

Edit: After playing with it for a bit, I'm even more confused than I was

This LINQ:

```
var vehicles = _context.Vehicles.Where(/*some additional filters*/)
return await vehicles.Select(v => v.Model).Distinct().Select(m => new ModelFilterDTO()
      {
          Name = m
      }).ToListAsync();
```

Gives the expected result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Model1"
  },
  { 
    "name": "Model2"
  },
  ...
]
```

Hovewer this LINQ:

```
var vehicles = _context.Vehicles.Where(/*some additional filters*/)
return await vehicles.Select(v => v.Model).Distinct().Select(m => new ModelFilterDTO()
      {
          Name = m,
          Codes = vehicles.Select(v=>v.Code).Distinct().Select(c => new CodeFilterDTO() 
          {
              Name = c
          })
      }).ToListAsync();
```

Gives result like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Model1",
    "codes": [
      {
        "name": "AAA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why is `Code` a string in `class Vehicle`?

Comment: @FortyTwo details of the domain. Code here is the three letter code related to the vehicle's operator

Answer (score 0):

Open for yourself `GroupBy` operator. Using double grouping you can achieve desired result.

```cs
var rawData = await _context.Vehicles
    .Where(/*some additional filters*/)
    .Select(v => new 
    {
        v.Model,
        v.RegistrationNumber,
        v.Code  
    })
    .ToListAsync(); // materialize minimum data

// perform grouping on the client side
var result = rawData
    .GroupBy(v => v.Model)
    .Select(gm => new ModelFilterDTO
    {
        Name = gm.Key,
        Codes = gm
            .GroupBy(x => x.Code)
            .Select(gc => new CodeFilterDTO
            {
                Name = gc.Key,
                RegistrationNumbers = gc.Select(x => x.RegistrationNumber).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, with client-side LINQ it's pretty trivial, I'm looking if it's possible to do that with only LINQ-to-SQL.

And I'm also really interested why exactly my LINQ doesn't work, because that's some really weird behavior on its part

Comment: It is not effectively translatable to the SQL LINQ query. So better to do client eval.

Comment: And I do not understand what groups data incorrectly EF Core (which is possible)  or Linq to Objects?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I know that SQL generated from the LINQ queries behaves as expected, returning correct data set. But the resulting object is incomplete and misses a lot of that data, so the problem must be somewhere between receiving the query results from the database and creating a final object

Comment: It can be just EF Core bug. You have created Eager Loading LINQ query which is not easy to translate. I know in this area a lot and just suggest to use client eval in such query, which in ten or more times effective.

Comment: And you can test your query in LINQ to Objects just by putting `ToList()` after filter.